# Can a PWA show a iframe with content stored on another server (subdomain of original domain)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cross-platform, progressive-web-apps

**Situation**:

i have 3 Apache 2.4 Webservers (running on 3 different Windows Server)

Server A -> https:\www.mydomain.com

Server B -> https:\www.subdomain1.mydomain.com

Server C -> https:\www.subdomain2.mydomain.com

On Server A - i have Index.html, manifest and serviceworker.js for a PWA.

Depending on login-informations (username and password, companyname) i will show in index.html a iFrame with content of Server B or Server C ....

**Question**

Is this possible?

Does PWA "allow" his?

What kind of server certificate must i use on 3 different Server ( wildcard?)

ThanX for help
Erich

Comment: PWA is just a regular website with added functionality. It does require HTTPS, so all of your iFrames sites should also be HTTPS else there will be the normal mixed content warning to the user.